# APNS PHP push notification issue

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I can run the APNS successfully on server. I get this message:

```
Fri, 03 Jun 2011 10:01:41 +0200 
ApnsPHP[29402]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... Fri, 03 Jun 2011 10:01:42 +0200 
ApnsPHP[29402]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195. Fri, 03 Jun 2011 10:01:42 +0200 
ApnsPHP[29402]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue. Fri, 03 Jun 2011 10:01:42 +0200 
ApnsPHP[29402]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-3] (1/3): 167 bytes. Fri, 03 Jun 2011 10:01:43 +0200 
ApnsPHP[29402]: INFO: Disconnected.
```

But when i run the application on device, i don't get push notification. I have written all the code and also created `entitlement.plist` file.

Can anyone please help me with this?? There is no debugging error as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Anks

Comment: It's hard to know with this little info. This could be an invalid payload (message, device token, length...), or you're using an invalid certificate, or even a wrong implementation within your app. There's no need to run the app when you send the push, because it will not show anything, but since you do, check if didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is not getting called. If certificate itself is invalide, i don't think server will show success message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me you are missing or you have an invalid app-token for your device.

Comment: Can you please explain, how do i check if it's valid or not??

Comment: Can you get the app-token-id print out on your iphone ? 
the very same app-token-id must be sent to the server (or some how the server must know your app-token-id) then it will push the payload (along with the app-token-id) to APNS gateway.  
Every app that needs to register for PUSH will call this function at least once "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken".  For more see: http://www.macoscoders.com/2009/05/17/iphone-apple-push-notification-service-apns/

Comment: Ok, My device is showing it's device id. I have copied same id to my PHP script. Now I'm running PHP script which already have my device id. So it should send that message to APNS and APNS should send that to my device.  FRom wwhatever message I'm getting on server, it's like it's sending message to APNS, but my device doesn't receive it. When i try to debug it's not calling didRegister...function also... Any idea??